# Does filtering "start with" cause high reads in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a hypothetical database that tracks street addresses worldwide. The partition key is the country and the sort key refers to the state and postal code of the street. For example one item may look like `CA#90210`.

(Clearly this has large localisation and distribution issues but this is a hypothetical)

I have 10,000 items in the US, if I query and filter the sort key to "starts with `CA`" (this may return 900 items) and the partition key to US, will DynamoDB only use RCUs for the 900 items that it found or the 10,000 items with "US" partition key?

On the same note, if I do use the postal code in the sort key, is it correct to keep it within another column in the database simply for my web application to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I query and filter the sort key to "starts with CA" (this may return 900 items) and the partition key to US, will DynamoDB only use RCUs for the 900 items

Yes, a `starts with` query will only touch the items the start with that value.

To put it another way `Query()` always requires the use an index, either a table with a composite primary key, or a local/global secondary index.

`Scan()` is the one to stay away from, every record in the table has to be read.

> if I do use the postal code in the sort key, is it correct to keep it within another column in the database simply for my web application to read?

Probably, otherwise your client would have to split the sort key itself for every record.  The extra space required to have the value twice isn't a big deal.